# Every time get result from else block cant get result from if block in android

Tags: android

Every time get result from else block cant get result from if block all time show result from else block,how to solve this problem please help me.Here is my code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    if (pd != null) {
        pd.dismiss();
    }
    try {
        Log.d("Request : 2 ", "" + result);
        if (result.equals("1")) {
            Toast.makeText(RegistrationPatient.this, "You Have Submited Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationPatient.this, DuraentMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            txt2.setText("not available");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: post from where your getting result? it might always return other than 1

Comment: have you checked what this line prints Log.d("Request : 2 ", "" + result); in logcat for result value, it may not be "1" ?

Comment: I would also like to point out that if you know that the result you are looking for is a number, you should be changing it to a number `Integer.valueOf(result)`. Your if may never be returning true because there is a stray character somewhere in the string (space, etc.) which will fail the equals check